# Windows PowerShell - Microsoft.Powershell.Commands.Utility not found

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0, powershell-5.1

I first discovered that PowerShell is not working correctly when I open my VisualStudio 2019. The Package Manager Console was not working as you can see below:

```
`Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands' or one of its dependencies.`
```

After I discovered this error i have done different things like: Done all updates available for Visual Studio 2019, all windows 10 updates, searched for the error everywhere but couldn´t find a similar question. Also tryed `sfc /scannow`.

I first tought it was only a Visual Studio error, but as I searched deeper, I found some suggestions like: Type `write-host 'test'` into Windows PowerShell, so I did.
[The error in Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilGeX.png).

Not just I can´t run simple commands like `write-host 'test'`, I also can´t run `Import-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` to install the missing commands.

Anybody up with an idea that not includes to reinstall windows?

Output of $PSVersionTable:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| PSVersion | 5.1.19041.1023 |
| PSEdition | Desktop |
| PSCompatibleVersions | {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...} |
| BuildVersion | 10.0.19041.1023 |
| CLRVersion | 4.0.30319.42000 |
| WSManStackVersion | 3.0 |
| PSRemotingProtocolVersion | 2.3 |
| SerializationVersion | 1.1.0.1 |

Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version: 21H1

Comment: It seems that the autoload of `Utility` PS module fails when you use `Write-Host`. The `Bad image format` exception lets think that the core snapin is ok and can load module but fails with this one. Probable causes : Damaged module, bad PSModulePath, 32/64 bits path conflict. Can you give us the output of `$env:PSModulePath` ? And the output of `get-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility | Format-Table ModuleType,Path -GroupBy Name -Wrap` ? (if `Format-Table` fails, try `get-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility | %{ $_.Path }`)

Comment: @Zilog80 Output of `$env:PSModulePath` is : `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`. `get-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility | Format-Table ModuleType,Path -GroupBy Name -Wrap` is not working and there is no Output for `get-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility | %{ $_.Path }`

Comment: Can you give us the cmd `dir` output of the folder `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\ `  ?

Comment: @Zilog80 there are two files:   
`-a----  07.12.2019  10:10  2473  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psd1  
-a----  07.12.2019  10:10  30592  Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility.psm1`

Comment: Curious... You've the 3.1.0.0 version of the module, not the 3.0.0.0. Why did the importer look for a 3.0.0.0... if you try with `import-module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility  -PassThru -RequiredVersion 3.1.0.0`, what is the output ?

Comment: @Zilog80 still the same error as in the picture of my post [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilGeX.png)

Comment: Can you temporary rename your modules user folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` in `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\ModulesTmp`  and check the `write-host` command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don´t know where the error came from, but I solved the problem by downloading the MediaCreationTool from Microsoft and created an ISO file.
After that I startet die Setup.exe from the ISO.
I "Reinstalled" Windows 10 with the option to keep my apps and documents. At first place I had an error `0xC1900101 - 0x2000c`. I disconnected my dockingstation and tryed it again. Now it run successfully and I can use PowerShell again.